# Downvoting doesn't warn that you're running out of votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, up-votes

People can only vote 40 times a day. Now when upvoting a question and you're running out of votes, the system warns you: "You have xx votes left today"

However, if you downvote, the system always says (at least if you don't have too much rep): "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved"

No matter if you have voted 35 times or more already.

My proposal is to give the warning a higher priority than the comment notification, so that if you do run out of votes, you will see the "You have xx votes left today" warning instead of the comment notification.
The reasoning being that if you did vote 35 times or more today already, you may also be aware that the system wants you to leave a comment. While you may not be aware that you're running out of votes.

Comment: +1 because that last point is an excellent one.

Comment: Note that the "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved" message will go away once you reach 2000 reputation.  At that point you do get the "You have xx votes left today" message on downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely convinced on this, so I'll play devil's advocate.

If you have low enough rep that you're still seeing the "post a comment" popup every time, I'd say it's more important to encourage you to be constructive (i.e. post a comment explaining your downvote) than to warn you that you're running out of votes. You get five warnings, and if your rep is low and your last five votes of the day are all downvotes, especially without comment, you may want to reconsider your voting habits.